# Alter method access to an argument using bytebuddy

Tags: java, reflection, byte-buddy

I have a case like the example below

```
public String test(Trail trail) {
  AnotherClass.access(trail);
  this.executeAnotherMethod(trail);
  futureCall(trail::end);
  return "emptyString";
}
```

And I want to use byte-buddy to do something like this

```
public String test(Trail trail) {
  Trail clonedTrail = trail.clone("test");
  AnotherClass.access(clonedTrail);
  this.executeAnotherMethod(clonedTrail);
  futureCall(clonedTrail::end);
  return "emptyString";
}
```

I have tried `Advice` to intercept the call but that messed up object reference. I have been diving through byte-buddy testcases as well as reading ASM, but haven't made great progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with advice by overwriting the argument.

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
static void enter(@Advice.Argument(readOnly = false) Trail trail) {
  trail = trail.clone("test");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem with the approach is the reference that it introduced a side effect to the trail reference; as the stack continues, other method will also alter the trail's reference and the futureCall (for example, 10 seconds later) will refer to a different object.

Comment: But the reference is only valid for the method's execution. The generated method body is 100% equivalent.